# Create Cgridview YII

Tags: yii, cgridview

> *Can anyone help me on how to create cgridview in Yii on front-end ,as I am a beginner in Yii*

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post');

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

Refer this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView